# Eloquent JavaScript 6.3 (Sequence Interface) Prototypes and Constructors

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor, prototype

In Eloquent JavaScript, chapter 6.3, there's a sequence interface question. In the solution we have a "make" function that is a function of a constructor called ArraySeq2. The code is `ArraqySeq2.make`.

My question is, why can't we set this function as a method that's part of the ArraySeq2 prototype? Why doesn't `ArraySeq2.prototype.make` work?

The question and full code below:

> Design an interface that abstracts iteration over a collection of
>   values. An object that provides this interface represents a sequence,
>   and the interface must somehow make it possible for code that uses
>   such an object to iterate over the sequence, looking at the element
>   values it is made up of and having some way to find out when the end
>   of the sequence is reached.
>
> When you have specified your interface, try to write a function
>   logFive that takes a sequence object and calls console.log on its
>   first five elements—or fewer, if the sequence has fewer than five
>   elements.
>
> Then implement an object type ArraySeq that wraps an array and allows
>   iteration over the array using the interface you designed. Implement
>   another object type RangeSeq that iterates over a range of integers
>   (taking from and to arguments to its constructor) instead.

```
function ArraySeq2(array, offset) {
    this.arr = array;
    this.offset = offset;
}

// this is the confusing part; "ArraySeq2.prototype.make" throws an error

ArraySeq2.make = function(array, offset) {
    if (offset === undefined) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    if (offset >= array.length) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new ArraySeq2(array, offset);
    }
};
ArraySeq2.prototype.rest = function() {
    return ArraySeq2.make(this.arr, this.offset + 1);
};
ArraySeq2.prototype.head = function() {
    return this.arr[this.offset];
};

function logFive2(sequence) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 && sequence != null; i++) {
        console.log(sequence.head());
        sequence = sequence.rest();
    }
}

logFive2(ArraySeq2.make([1, 2]));
// → 1
// → 2
```

Some explanation on the answer below, to help answers:

> You can expose a method for getting the current element (without
>   advancing any counter) and another for getting a new sequence that
>   represents the remaining elements after the current one (or a special
>   value if the end of the sequence is reached). This is quite elegant—a
>   sequence value will “stay itself” even after it is used and can thus
>   be shared with other code without worrying about what might happen to
>   it. It is, unfortunately, also somewhat inefficient in a language like
>   JavaScript because it involves creating a lot of objects during
>   iteration.
>
> This alternative approach represents the empty sequence as null, and
>   gives non-empty sequences two methods:
>
> - head() returns the element at the start of the sequence.
> - rest() returns the rest of the sequence, or null if there are no   elemements left.
>
> Because a JavaScript constructor can not return null, we add a make
>   function to constructors of this type of sequence, which constructs a
>   sequence, or returns null if the resulting sequence would be empty.

Comment: If you put `make` on the prototype, then you have to call it using `ArraySeq2.prototype.make()` or create an instance of `ArraySeq2` in order to call it.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. The `make` function is basically repeating the creation of a new instance. If I put `make` as a prototype of `ArraySeq2`, I have to both create an instance of `ArraySeq2` and use `make`, which is kind of repetitive.

Comment: If I wanted a prototype, I'd have to say `ArraySeq2.prototype.make`, `return new ArraySeq2().make(this.arr, this.offset + 1);`, and `console.log(   logFive2( new ArraySeq2().make([1, 2]) )   )`.